# I'd like to make a websocket handshake with delphi6

Tags: delphi, md5, websocket, delphi-6, handshake

I'm trying to build a websocket server on Delphi6 using the draft hixie-76 and i have a problem with the handshake.

The md5 fingerprint i get with the three parts does not seem to be correct when i try it,  but when i use the same algorythm with the exemple given in the protocole spec i get the good md5 response...

I'm processing like this, transform the number found in key1 divided by the number of spaces in a 32 bits word, same with key2 and finally adding the last 8 bytes (key3) to get a 128 bits string which i use as md5 entry.

using 155712099, 173347027 for key1 and key2 and 'Tm[K T2u' for key3, i get the correct md5 fingerprint and so i don't understand why this algo won't give a correct fingerprint to the client

here is an exemple of what i receive :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1  
Upgrade: WebSocket  
Connection: Upgrade  
Host: localhost:8018  
Origin: null  
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 4  102(2 6U 2 3  18  
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 69V86`6t)e 0 2     42  


M]Rzÿõ&
```

and the handshake i give in response

```
HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake  
Upgrade: WebSocket  
Connection: Upgrade  
Sec-WebSocket-Origin: null  
Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8018/  


µ&Mq˜8èõÙZÙ,hœi
```

Maybye there's another probleme with my response but it reall seems that i have a problem with my md5 fingerprint.

Does anyone see where my mistake is??

Thanks in advance for your help

**Update**

I have seen this unit but unless i'm very bad at reading, the handshake part of this class does not calculate any md5 sum, i think it uses an older version of the protocol and not the current (76)

When i look at the following code i see that the answer is written without any md5 response.

`  try
    // Read request headers
    HandshakeRequest := TWebSocketRequest.Create(ServerConnection);

```
// Send response headers
ServerConnection.WriteLn('HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake');
ServerConnection.WriteLn('Upgrade: WebSocket');
ServerConnection.WriteLn('Connection: Upgrade');
ServerConnection.WriteLn('WebSocket-Origin: ' + HandshakeRequest.Origin);
ServerConnection.WriteLn('WebSocket-Location: ws://' + HandshakeRequest.Host + '/');

// End handshake
ServerConnection.WriteLn;
ServerConnection.WriteLn;

HandshakeResponseSent := True;
```

except
    on E: TWebSocketHandshakeException do
    begin
      // Close the connection if the handshake failed
      ServerConnection.Disconnect;
    end;`

Thanks again

**Update 2011 04 14**

I have finally found where the problem was...

i was building my response like that :

`resp := [...] +'Sec-WebSocket-Origin: '+ origin + #13#10 +

               #13#10#13#10 +

               md5response;`
so there was 3 0x0D 0x0A instead of 2 before the md5 fingerprint ...

Since i cannot answer my own question i won't be able to mark it solve but it is! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you need to add more information that won't fit as a comment under an answer, please just edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a websocket class in google code for Delphi that might give you the answer:

http://code.google.com/p/delphiws/source/browse/trunk/source/uWebSocket.pas?r=4